# Create ASCII Textfile using CreateTextFile methode (VBA)

Tags: vba, ascii, text-files

I'm trying to create an ASCII file via VBA using the [CreateTextFile method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/createtextfile-method):

```
Dim FSO As Object
Dim TextFile As Object
Dim Path As String
Path = "C:\somefolder\Textfile.txt"
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set TextFile = FSO.CreateTextFile(Path, True, False)
```

Testing with `TextFile.WriteLine "Test öäüß"` the non-extended set characters are visible when opening the text file in Notepad therefore I assume an extended set has been created, is this correct? Is there a way to create an ASCII file without an extended character set?

Comment: But the characters you show have ASCII codes: (246, 248, 252, 223). Why do you try creating an ASCII file when suspecting the use of special characters and not using the `Unicode` (`True`) parameter, which creates UTF16 file?

Comment: @FaneDuru I know, but it's ASCII with an extended character set (8 bit), I'm trying to create an ASCII file without an extended character set (7 bit / 128 characters). And I'm not suspecting the use of "special characters", I just used them to check if the ASCII file is actually 7 bit, if it is they shouldn't be displayed (as far as I understand).

Comment: @Albin You can't say "ASCII with an extended character set" and stop there. You must then say which codepage that is, because people have had very different ideas about what goes into the range 128-256. See https://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html. And then later when you open that file, you must also tell the viewing program to use the same codepage that you used when writing that file. You cannot even do that with Notepad. You can with Notepad++.

Comment: Then, the answer at your question would be: `CreateTextFile` creates a 8 bits file (including extended characters).

Comment: @GSerg Thanks for the info, that's a helpful link! I actually want to use ASCII without the extended character set. If this is the case, do I still have to worry about the code page? As far as I understand the first 128 characters are encoded the same way regardless of the code page?!

Comment: @FaneDuru Thanks, that's what I thought. After reading up a bit on ASCII (as GSerg suggested), I think I understand a bit more. If I use ASCII (7 bit) there are (usually) still 8 bits used to encode each character (and not 7 bits as I initially assumed), correct? Which code page does VBA use to encode ASCII, is that dependent on the system settings?

Comment: @Albin VBA uses the current system codepage. Which is not relevant because here FSO is doing the conversion. It is doing the same though.

Comment: Are you also interested in other methods to create ASCII text files using VBA?